# Android SDK version 23.6

Tags: java, android, sdk

Does it support java 8 yet? 
Eclipse is displaying this as a problem, surely it does support 8 by now? In the release notes for revision 23.6 it says java 7 or higher, does this mean java 8 is included or? Wish they'd be more specific about such details. Anyway, if it does support java 8 i cannot get it to work.

Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.8' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

The peculiar thing is, it's saying 5 or 6 yet it's allowing me to use 7 but not 8?

Comment: So what's the problem actually ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it support java 8 yet?

No.  It doesn't.  To date, no version of Android supports the Java 8 language.

> Anyway, if it does support java 8 i cannot get it to work.

That is unfortunate.  But don't give up hope just yet.  Take a look at the [retrolambda project](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).